# The value is not set for the parameter number 0

Tags: sql-server-2008, remote-access, sqljdbc

I have a Store Procedure and it run correctly. I can login this database using remote connection.
I installed sqljdbc.jar and added into tomcat/common/lib .But When I run my application, I couldn't get Store Procedure's results from database. I get this error message  " The value is not set for the parameter number 0." How can I solve this problem?

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_mesaiKontrol]

@mesai_durum AS NVARCHAR(20) OUTPUT,
@hangi_gun AS NVARCHAR(10) OUTPUT,
@menu AS NVARCHAR(20)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @tod INT;
DECLARE @gun NVARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @haftaici_MIN nvarchar(5);
DECLARE @haftaici_MAX nvarchar(5);
DECLARE @haftasonu_MIN nvarchar(5);
DECLARE @haftasonu_MAX nvarchar(5);
DECLARE @menu_ad nvarchar(20);

SET @tod = (SELECT (100*DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE())+ DATEPART(MINUTE,GETDATE())))
SET @gun=(SELECT dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(GETDATE()));
SET @haftaici_MIN =(SELECT HaftaIci_MIN FROM dbo.Mesai_Kontrol WHERE Menu = @menu);
SET @haftaici_MAX =(SELECT HaftaIci_MAX FROM dbo.Mesai_Kontrol WHERE Menu = @menu);
SET @haftasonu_MIN =(SELECT HaftaSonu_MIN FROM dbo.Mesai_Kontrol WHERE Menu = @menu);
SET @haftasonu_MAX =(SELECT HaftaSonu_MAX FROM dbo.Mesai_Kontrol WHERE Menu = @menu);


----------------------------------------  -----------------------------------------------
IF(@gun IN ('Pazartesi', 'Sali', 'Carsamba', 'Persembe', 'Cuma'))
  IF(@tod>=@haftaici_MIN AND @tod<=@haftaici_MAX )
    BEGIN
        SET @mesai_durum='mesai_ici'
        SET @hangi_gun=@gun
        Select @mesai_durum AS MesaiDurumu 
        Select @hangi_gun   AS GUN
    END 
  ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @mesai_durum='mesai_disi'
        SET @hangi_gun=@gun
        Select @mesai_durum AS MesaiDurumu
        Select @hangi_gun   AS GUN
    END

-------------------------------------------  -------------------------------------------
ELSE IF(@gun IN('Cumartesi','Pazar'))
 IF(@tod>=@haftasonu_MIN AND @tod<=@haftasonu_MAX )
    BEGIN
        SET @mesai_durum='mesai_ici'
        SET @hangi_gun=@gun
        Select @mesai_durum AS MesaiDurumu
        Select @hangi_gun   AS GUN
    END
 ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @mesai_durum='mesai_disi'
        SET @hangi_gun=@gun
        Select @mesai_durum AS MesaiDurumu
        Select @hangi_gun   AS GUN
    END

END
```

Comment: Without seeing the code that you use to execute the sp in java it's kind of hard to give any informed suggestions at all, so please update the question with relevant code.

Comment: Posting the SP is a good start, but as the error is most likely in the Java code, that would be really helpful too :)

Comment: I shared SP codes. it run correctly when I invoke it from my application on Eclipse.I get right results. but When I try to get results using apache tomcat, I get this message " The value is not set for the parameter number 0."

Comment: Side note: [Creating Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669(v=sql.105).aspx): "We recommend that you do not create any stored procedures using **sp_** as a prefix. SQL Server uses the **sp_** prefix to designate system stored procedures."

Comment: @user2549380 If the SP works in your local application in Eclipse but not in Tomcat I'm guessing that the java code that is run in Tomcat differs in some way from what you run in the application, but without seeing the code there's no way of knowing. Maybe you could run a trace on the SQL server to see if the query is executed with the correct parameters when run from Tomcat.

Comment: Hi, this problem is solved. We recognized that Apache tomcat java version doesn't support to application java version. Problem is solved  upgrading tomcat java version. Thank you for your help